# Query and sort data from inside one of tables (Azure Log Analytics)

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I have following query which give me defender av Endpoint Protection client health report from server.

```
Event | where EventLog contains "defender" | where EventID == 1151
```

Inside query are table "RenderedDescription" which contains data "Antivirus signature age: 100" what I would like to use (+ a lot useless to me). Picture show format how data is in that table. The number shows how old Defender definitions are.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGaXE.png)

Is is even possible to sort and query data from inside table in Log analytics? I would like to have query which would only display events if Antivirus signature age number would be bigger than 100

I tried to explain this as good as possible so hope you understood what I ment.

Comment: the "RenderedDescription" is a table in azure log analytics? and in the screenshot, I can not see the data "Antivirus signature age: 100". Can you please explain it more clear? It's better to add some screenshots which can help understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually just query and sort data is very easy. But you should provide more details as per my comment.

And now I assume that the `RenderedDescription` is a table in Azure log analytics like the table named `Event`.

And I also assume the `Antivirus signature age` is a column, then you can try the query below:

```
RenderedDescription
| where "Antivirus signature age" > 100
```

If I have some misunderstandings, please correct me.

By the way, the current screenshot in your post is not good enough. And it's better to provide other screenshots of structure(includes the columns especially the data "Antivirus signature age: 100" in which column) of the table `RenderedDescription`.